# Calling TS function from HTML select tag don't work properly

Tags: html, typescript

I want to call a TS function from HTML select tag. I found a way to do it but for some unknown reason it sends me error massage.

I use onChange in my select tag to call the function. In the function I use the following method to reach the option's value in the select tag:

My HTML code:

```
<select id="mySelect" (change)="SelectLanguage()">
  <option value="1">English</option>
  <option value="2">Romanian</option>
  <option value="3">Hungarian</option>
</select>
```

My TS code:

```
SelectLanguage() {
    const e = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    const value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log('e: ', value);
    this.UploadArrays(value);
}
```

I get the following error massage from this line:

```
const value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

saying that: 'Property options/selecteIndex does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' ', however by logging out the value variable I see that it have the right value ... so this line is working. Everything else is working fine but still get this error massage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to cast the element to [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), like so:

```
const e = document.getElementById('mySelect') as HTMLSelectElement
```

Then you will have all the properties you need.

Comment: Thank you sir for your quick answer, it did the thing. Still wonder why was it working.

Comment: Because `HTMLElement` doesn't have an `options` property, but `HTMLSelectElement` does. Typescript aspires to be a statically typed language, and won't let you access properties that aren't there. It's a Good Thing.